# How can i duplicate rows by looking my two cloumns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have one big table like this :

```
**StartIp,EndIp,value**
(1.0.0.9,1.0.0.18,a)
(172.0.0.2,180.0.0.1,c)
```

I want result like this :

```
(1.0.0.9,a)
(1.0.0.10,a)
(1.0.0.11,a)
.
.
.
(1.0.0.18,a)
(172.0.0.2,c)
.
.
(180.0.0.1.c)
```

I wrote to find this function to find ips between range

```
import java.net.InetAddress
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}

object ExpandIpRange {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Define the start and end IP addresses
    val startIp = "192.168.0.1"
    val endIp = "192.168.0.5"

    // Create a SparkSession
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("ExpandIpRange")
      .getOrCreate()

    try {
      // Define a function to expand an IP range
      def expandIpRange(startIp: String, endIp: String): Seq[String] = {
        val startAddress = InetAddress.getByName(startIp)
        val endAddress = InetAddress.getByName(endIp)

        // Convert the IP addresses to integers
        val startInt = ipToInt(startAddress)
        val endInt = ipToInt(endAddress)

        // Create a sequence of IP addresses
        (startInt to endInt).map(intToIp)
      }

      // Define a function to convert an IP address to an integer
      def ipToInt(address: InetAddress): Int = {
        val bytes = address.getAddress
        ((bytes(0) & 0xFF) << 24) |
          ((bytes(1) & 0xFF) << 16) |
          ((bytes(2) & 0xFF) << 8) |
          (bytes(3) & 0xFF)
      }

      // Define a function to convert an integer to an IP address
      def intToIp(address: Int): String = {
        InetAddress.getByAddress(intToBytes(address)).getHostAddress
      }

      // Define a function to convert an integer to a byte array
      def intToBytes(address: Int): Array[Byte] = {
        Array(
          ((address >> 24) & 0xFF).toByte,
          ((address >> 16) & 0xFF).toByte,
          ((address >> 8) & 0xFF).toByte,
          (address & 0xFF).toByte
        )
      }

      // Expand the IP range
      val ips = expandIpRange(startIp, endIp)

      // Convert the IP addresses to rows
      val rows = ips.map(ip => Row(ip))
```

How can i apply to my dataframe

I have 2 billion records so i need to do it in a good way

Answer (score 0):

You have the function that solve the ip ranges and return a Seq of what you need

```
def expandIpRange(startIp: String, endIp: String): Seq[String]
```

what about something like

```
dataframeWithIpRanges
  .flatMap { row =>
    expandIpRange(row.startIp, row.endIp)
      .map(range => Row(range, row.value)
  }
```

Don't know exactly the spark syntax, but the idea would be to use `flatMap` where you will pass a function (the one that create the list of IPs based on the ranged received by parameter), then transform the list in a listo of `Row(IP, value)` which is the expected result you are looking for.